# Refresh a web picture every n-seconds in a Windows RT app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I picked a sample in VisualStudio and started to modify it to create a traffic app with pictures from webcams (which update let's say every 10 seconds). I have a SampleData.json file in which I have the items, sample below.

```
{"Groups":[
  {
    "UniqueId": "Group-1",
    "Title": "Primorska in Notranjska",
    "Subtitle": "Group subtitle: 1",
    "ImagePath": "Assets/Pics/primorska.jpg",
    "Description" : "Group Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempor scelerisque lorem in vehicula. Aliquam tincidunt, lacus ut sagittis tristique, turpis massa volutpat augue, eu rutrum ligula ante a ante",
    "Items":
    [
      {
        "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-1",
        "Title": "A1/E61/E70 Ljubljana - Koper, priključek Brezovica",
        "Subtitle": "Item Subtitle: 1",
        "ImagePath": "Assets/LightGray.png",
        "Description" : "",
        "Content" : "A1/E61/E70 Ljubljana - Koper, priključek Brezovica, pogled proti Postojni",
        "PicSource" : "http://kamere.dars.si/kamere/ljubljana/K01_Brezovica_Po.jpg"
      },
```

Than I bind the picture to every item:

```
<Image Source="{Binding PicSource}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,88,440,10" 
       Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

How can I refresh it every n-seconds ?

EDIT: I set the ViewModel in SampleDataSource:

```
        public SampleDataItem(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description, String content, String picSource)
    {
        this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Subtitle = subtitle;
        this.Description = description;
        this.ImagePath = imagePath;
        this.Content = content;
        this.PicSource = picSource;
    }
```

..later
            public string PicSource { get; private set; }
..later
            private async Task GetSampleDataAsync()
        {
            if (this._groups.Count != 0)
                return;

```
        Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json");

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
        string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

        foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
        {
            JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
            SampleDataGroup group = new SampleDataGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Description"].GetString());

            foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
            {
                JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                group.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Description"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Content"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["PicSource"].GetString()));
            }
            this.Groups.Add(group);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the source from code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(n);
    timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        //  ...
        //  image.Source = ...
    };
    timer.Start();           
}
```

Comment: How can I bind the photo in the same way I did with XAML ?

Comment: If `PicSource` is MVVM property then just change value of it, it will be reflected in image.

Comment: Is this code right: 'Image image = new Image(); image.Source = ("{Binding PicSource}");' I get an error..

Comment: @Skynet, You're trying to combine XAML syntax with C#. What Xyroid meant is that, PicSource is an object in your ViewModel somewhere. If you update PicSource, and the MVVM is correct, it will automatically update the UI. PicSource has to be changed with a new value (the Source of the new Picture)

Comment: @VasileMarianFălămaș oh, sorry, I updated the post with more info.